# Can a CRT be made for an arbitrary collection of ideals?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, ideals, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $\{I_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be an arbitrary family of ideals of a commutative ring $R$.  Suppose that $I_{\alpha} + I_{\beta} = R$ for all $\alpha \neq \beta$.

Then is there a corresponding situation if we take the infinite product to be $\prod_{\alpha \in A} R/I_{\alpha}$ or can you only apply it to finitely many ideals?

Define a directed system to be for any $B \subset A$, $M_{B} = \prod_{b \in B} R/I_{b}$.  Then for $B \subset C$, clearly we have an embedding $f_{BC}:B \hookrightarrow C$, and with all maps $(M_B, f_{BC})$ forms a directed system.

So can't we take the direct limit of $M_B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the canonical map $R\to \prod R/I_\alpha$ will typically not be surjective.  For instance, let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and let the $I_\alpha$ be the ideals $(p)$ for all primes $p$.  Then the product $\prod_p\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is uncountable, so there cannot be a surjection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to it.

Comment: What about my comment on direct limit.  Would that take us to a ring other than $\prod R/I_a$?

Comment: I don't know what your embedding $f_{BC}$ is supposed to be (there is no such ring embedding).  In any case, if you were to construct such a direct limit, then $R$ probably wouldn't even map to it at all.  Again, I suggest you think about the example $R=\mathbb{Z}$ with all the primes and see what would happen in that case.